# Formula to convert Local coordinates to world coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d

Can someone give me the formula?
I have a vector3d which represents the position of a vertex in local coordinates, I have a Matrix3d that represents the rotation and position of the object which this vertex is part of it's geometry, how do I convert the local position of this vertex to the coordinates of the world?

Comment: I think you need **Matrix3D** that represents vertex translation then you multiply it to container's **Matrix3D** with https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html#append() I think which one is appendant and which one is appendee is important, but you have just 2 options so it won't hurt you to just try.

Comment: If that matrix is in global coordinates, then to get that vertex's global coords you need to invert the matrix, then multiply the result to the vector2d of yours. Make sure to check `matrix3D::invert()` result, if it's false, you're screwed.

Comment: "I think you need Matrix3D that represents vertex translation" -- how do I create this matrix3d? like this: m=new matrix3d; m..prependTranslation(v.x,v.y,v.z); or like this m.position.x=v.x; m.position.y=v.y; m.position.z=v.z;  ?

Comment: @danielkotzer I am kind of **sad** because these two ways give the same result and it took me about 3 minutes to test it so would it took you. You should not be afraid to test things yourself.

Comment: Sorry but it seems to me that every little mismatch I'm doing on stage3D, gives me completely different result, so I'm not confident enough to know, if what seems to be the same to me, has some unknown effect on the end result.

Comment: did this: var m3d:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();  
obj.Transform.copyToMatrix3D(m3d);
var m2:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
m2.appendTranslation(V.x,V.y,V.z);
m2.append(m3d);
V = new Vector3D(m2.position.x,m2.position.y,m2.position.z); didn't work, the object keeps turning, even when it shouldn't rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it's working, I had a problem with keeping the original vertex3d, and I played with the order and this is working, thank you very much, here is the code, I did have to use m2.invert(); here is the code:

```
var m3d:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();      
obj.Transform.copyToMatrix3D(m3d);
var m2:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
m2.append(m3d);
m2.invert();
m2.prependTranslation(obj.BoundingBox[i].x,obj.BoundingBox[i].y,obj.BoundingBox[i].z);
obj.BoundingBox[i] = new Vector3D(m2.position.x,m2.position.y,m2.position.z);
```

in fact as I did it in the first place was also OK:

```
var m3d:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();      
obj.Transform.copyToMatrix3D(m3d);
m3d.invert();
obj.BoundingBox[i] = m3d.transformVector(obj.BoundingBox[i]);
```

The only thing I was missing was the invert(); and I wish I knew what it is for...
Some people told me I have to append (or prepend) the object matrix and then the world matrix, which makes sense, but adding the world matrix only caused me problems,  while the invert(); made it good, but why?

Vesper, you are the one suggested it, thanks but why?

I know why, someone experienced gave me the answer: the camera shows everything mirrored, when you go left the world seems to be moving right, so you need to invert.